# How to test not equal with matcher in flutter

Tags: testing, flutter, dart, matcher

I'm doing testing on render objects in Flutter. I'd like to check for inequality like this (simplified):

```
testWidgets('render object heights not equal', (WidgetTester tester) async {

  final renderObjectOneHeight = 10;
  final renderObjectTwoHeight = 11;

  expect(renderObjectOneHeight, notEqual(renderObjectTwoHeight));
});
```

I made up `notEqual` because it doesn't exist. This doesn't work either:

- `!equals`

*I found a solution that works so I am posting my answer below Q&A style. I welcome any better solutions, though.*

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use `isNot()` to negate the `equals()` matcher.

```dart
final x = 1;
final y = 2;

expect(x, isNot(equals(y)));
```

Or as mentioned in the comments:

```dart
expect(x != y, true)
```

That actually seems a bit more readable to me.

Comment: A lot of various matchers are documented in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/flutter_test-library.html

Comment: Why don't use just `expect(x != y, true)`?

Comment: @BambinoUA, Good question.

Comment: @ BambinoUA & @Suragch the reason `expect(x, isNot(equals(y)));`should be preferred over `expect(x != y, true)` is that the first one will give you the actual comparison upon the test failing while the later will just complain expected true actual false which makes a second run with the debugger necessary to gain more insights. (But I agree ;D the first one reads better)

Answer (score 3):

Since the behavior for the `matcher` argument of `expect()`, as well as the argument to `isNot()`, is to [treat non-function values as if wrapped in `equals()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_matcher/wrapMatcher.html), you can succinctly write the following without using `equals()`:

```
expect(123, 123);
expect(123, isNot(456));
```

Your example would then be

```
testWidgets('render object heights not equal', (WidgetTester tester) async {

  final renderObjectOneHeight = 10;
  final renderObjectTwoHeight = 11;

  expect(renderObjectOneHeight, isNot(renderObjectTwoHeight));
});
```